# Arithmetical expressions in bash switch

Tags: bash, syntax, expression

I want this script to load string argument, check its length and if its length is 1, then assign 1 to a variable, else assign a arithmetical expression to it. I'm having problems with the bash syntax and can't make it work. Any help would be appreciated. This is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

stringArg=$1
let myVariable=1
case "${#stringArg}" in
 1) myVariable=1 ;;
 *) myVariable="${#stringArg}*2-2" ;;
esac

echo $myVariable
```

Running this with `./test.sh 123` outputs `3*2-2`, but I want it to print `4`.

Comment: Insert  after `#!/bin/bash` in a new line `declare -i myVariable` to set integer attribute.

Comment: Do you really want to assign the expression, or the *result* of the expression, to `myVariable`?

Comment: Don't bother with the integer attribute; it doesn't apply to most of the situations you would really want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are the just assigning the expression to the variable not the actual value after evaluation.

You can evaluate expressions in various ways, `$(())` or `bc` etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

stringArg=$1
let myVariable=1
case "${#stringArg}" in
 1) myVariable=1 ;;
 *) myVariable="${#stringArg}*2-2" ;;
esac

echo $(( $myVariable ))
```